# Polymer with Cordova neon-animation doesn't work

Tags: cordova, polymer-1.0

I have use neon-animation to change page. It's work on browser. However, when I build with cordova the attr-for-selected is change but neon-animated-pages doesn't change.
My android version is 4.4.1, cordova version is 5.1.1

```
<dom-module id="x-test">
  <template>
    <neon-animated-pages id="pages" 
                                 selected="{{page}}" 
                                 attr-for-selected="data-page"
                                 entry-animation="{{entryAnimation}}" 
                                 exit-animation="{{exitAnimation}}"> 

      <neon-animatable data-page="detail">
        This is detail page
        <paper-button id='forward' on-click="forward">forward</paper-button>
      </neon-animatable>

      <neon-animatable data-page="map">
        This is map page
        <paper-button id='back' on-click="back">back</paper-button>
      </neon-animatable>          

    </neon-animated-pages>


  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-test',
      properties: {
        page: {
          value: "detail",
          type: String,
          notify: true
        },
        entryAnimation: {
          value: "slide-from-left-animation",
          type: String,
          notify: true                  
        },
        exitAnimation: {
          value: "slide-right-animation",
          type: String,
          notify: true                  
        }
      }, 
      forward: function(e){
        this.entryAnimation = 'slide-from-left-animation';
        this.exitAnimation = 'slide-right-animation';           
        this.page = "map";
        alert("forward select "+this.page);
      },
      back: function(e){
        this.entryAnimation = 'slide-from-right-animation';
        this.exitAnimation = 'slide-left-animation';    
        this.page = "detail";
        alert("back select "+this.page);
      }          
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

This is example in jsbin: http://jsbin.com/yuhovodose/edit?html,output

In the picture can see that the page properties has been set !!

[Example in my mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYf7i.png)

Comment: Please put your code in the question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry, I always find the question, this is the first time ask the question, thought that only put the code in jsbin the same

Comment: And I have solved it by myself... Just I make a mistake use the same variable... and cost cordova can't decide which page should go, the example in jsbin still is a very easy example, if any one want to use neon-animation can take a look!